# Android Augmented reality framework for android

Tags: android, augmented-reality, android-augmented-reality

So, I have a need of some kind of framework for AR that will let me do the following:

I need to get the location displayed on camera with some pins, also, this must work indoors, as well as outdoors.

What thing would you recommend?

Comment: Look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40107981/tglaugmentedrealityview-like-library-for-android-locations-on-camera-preview/40159416#40159416

Answer (score 0):

I really like this [open source implementation](https://www.androidexperiments.com/experiment/landmarker). Using Gradle and you have access to the source code.