# TGLAugmentedRealityView like library FOR ANDROID? (Locations on camera preview)

Tags: android, android-augmented-reality

So I would like to use a very similar library for Android just like [TGLAugmentedRealityView](https://github.com/gleue/TGLAugmentedRealityView)

It's **pops view's to the camera preview based on your and the target's location.**

I hardly find anything useful for Android.

Please help if you can.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about that [open source experiment](https://www.androidexperiments.com/experiment/landmarker) LandMarker. Well written and you have access to the source code.

Comment: It doesnt have camera preview but the bounty gona end in 1 hour so here you go.

Comment: Thanks! Just add a SurfaceView (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html) for the camera preview and those pins with annotations on top of it. That should do it.

Answer (score 1):

**Intro**

In my opinion the best software for cross platform augment reality that do what you asked for was Metaio, but Metaio has been acquired by apple last year and they just with out more information about the future of the product shot-down the product availability in end of 2015, and I am excited to see what will happen next.

Metaio offered a free version for developer that do what you asked for. And I have tried it in few projects.

**What is alternative**
I would suggest you take look for following open source libraries, that I have researched recently for another project, I will suggest you take look for:

- https://artoolkit.org
- http://www.openspace3d.com
- http://www.mixare.org
- http://bitstars.github.io/droidar

Here is some paid version:

- https://www.vuforia.com
- http://www.augment.com
- https://www.layar.com
- http://www.arlab.com/arbrowser
- http://www.wikitude.com/products/wikitude-sdk
- https://www.aurasma.com

Library (python, c#, java and android) where you can develop your own computer vision stuff including augment reality:

- http://opencv.org
- http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html

Few other links:

- https://www.beyondreality.nl/in2ar
- https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-augment-reality-framework
- https://sourceforge.net/projects/lookar

It is hard to suggest specific one most of them can do what you asking for.

I would also leave a link where you can find a list and comparison of available augment reality libraries/software:

- http://socialcompare.com/en/comparison/augmented-reality-sdks
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_augmented_reality_software

Comment: I have tried most of these. The common thing among these libraries that they were developed years ago (some of them back in the days with Eclipse) and they just don't run in an up to date Android Studio with the newest Android SDK, newest gradle. Even the paid ones. Sadly.

Comment: I understand you, it is a bit sad but that is I think so far the fact is, it is a niche area where the development is as smoothly as other areas. I thought any way providing what I have of knowledge since I work with Augment reality. I was  hope that Apple will relrease metaio in new version. that is the only hope left, if none other release some thing new. Keep it up